# View raw XML from JAXRS WebClient

Tags: java, xml, cxf, jax-rs, webclient

I'm having a hard time finding the solution to this, perhaps because my terminology is wrong.

What I would like to do is be able to log the RAW xml returned when I call `.get()` on a **JAXRS WebClient**.

The current setup I have does the unmarshalling without any problems when I perform this:

```
MyObject result = (MyObject) client.get(MyObject.class);
```

But, I'd like to see what is actually returned by the server in the form of XML to System.out while I debug.

Comment: what JAXRS implementation do you use?

Comment: Apache CXF 2.6.3 is the implementation I'm using.

Comment: then you can turn on logging in configuration: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-Logging

Comment: I don't want to see the raw XML via logging though. I'd like to able to access it from the WebClient in my code somehow. Is that something that is possible to do?

Comment: I don't think you can retrieve it from client, but you can still debug CXF itself. If your intention is to output XML to system out then logging should be ok for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the raw XML returned the following way:

`String rawXml = client.get(String.class)`

I was then able to inspect the raw XML as well as pass it to my logger within the class if needed.